# how to get the name of the columns of a csv to avoid writing "key1": row [1], "key2": row [2]

Tags: python

Basically I want to avoid if I have for example 9 columns in my csv, write them in this inefficient way:

```
myArray.append({"word":row[0],"score":row[1],"sub":row[2],"emotion":row[3],"tipo_palabra":row[4],"lemma":row[5],"empresa":row[6], "entidad":row[7],"lugar":row[8],"tiempo":row[9] })
```

I would like to know if there is any way to obtain the value of the column and assign it the corresponding value. I know what to do for a json with something like this:

for idx, key in enumerate (myJson.keys ()):
 
but I do not know what would be the equivalent to do it in the case of a csv.In my csv I have these columns:

```
word,score,sub,emotion,tipo_palabra,lemma,empresa, entidad,lugar,tiempo
```

and I want to get them dynamically from my file.

How can I avoid defining the fields one by one? I want to make the json that I'm building the key be the name of the column and the value that corresponds to the row

```
with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as File:  
    reader = csv.reader(File,delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:
        myArray.append({"word":row[0],"score":row[1],"sub":row[2],"emotion":row[3],"tipo_palabra":row[4],"lemma":row[5],"empresa":row[6], "entidad":row[7],"lugar":row[8],"tiempo":row[9] })
File.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personnal favorite when I need to do something while reading, and not only read

```
output = []
with open(file) as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='|')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        dict_row = {}
        for i,field in enumerate(header):
             #do stuff but if you want to read
             dict_row[field] = row[i]
    output += [dict_row]
```

Comment: not works for me.. this is the result: [{'word|score|sub|emotion|tipo_palabra|lemma|empresa|entidad|lugar|tiempo': 'tardísimo|8|Superlativos Negativos|Superlativos Negativos|Adjetivo|tardísimo||||'}]

Comment: Sorry , need to specify delimiter then, just edited it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv.DictReader` for this like,

Hoping your csv file looks like,

```
$ cat some.csv
word|score|sub|emotion|tipo_palabra|lemma|empresa| entidad|lugar|tiempo
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10
11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99|1100
```

Then you can do,

```
$ cat some.py
import csv
myArray = []
with open('some.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
       myArray.append(dict(row))
```

And the output,

```
$ python3 some.py
[{'word': '1', 'score': '2', 'sub': '3', 'emotion': '4', 'tipo_palabra': '5', 'lemma': '6', 'empresa': '7', ' entidad': '8', 'lugar': '9', 'tiempo': '10'}, {'word': '11', 'score': '22', 'sub': '33', 'emotion': '44', 'tipo_palabra': '55', 'lemma': '66', 'empresa': '77', ' entidad': '88', 'lugar': '99', 'tiempo': '1100'}]
```

Comment: hey thanks, I am getting this: [OrderedDict([('word', 'abandonados'), ('score', '1'), ('sub', 'Decepcionado'), ('emotion', 'Tristeza'), ('tipo_palabra', 'Adjetivo'), ('lemma', 'abandonado'), ('empresa', ''), ('entidad', ''), ('lugar', ''), ('tiempo', '')])... how can I avoid creating arrays and have a cleaner structure like this: [{"key1": value1, "key2", value2}, {"key1": value1, "key2", value2}]

Comment: Use `myArray.append(dict(row))`. `OrderedDict` and `dict` can be accessed the same way. The only difference is `OrderedDicts` are ordered :). If you want, you can just ask it to make it a `dict` rather than `OrderedDict`

Comment: you are a genious, but is different like this:like this: [{"key1": value1, "key2", value2}, {"key1": value1, "key2", value2}]   --> [OrderedDict([('word', 'abandonados'), ('score', '1'), ('sub', 'Decepcionado'), ('emotion', 'Tristeza'), ('tipo_palabra', 'Adjetivo'), ('lemma', 'abandonado'), ('empresa', ''), ('entidad', ''), ('lugar', ''), ('tiempo', '')]), OrderedDict([('word', 'abandonado'), ('score', '1'), ('sub', 'Decepcionado'), ('emotion', 'Tristeza'), ('tipo_palabra', 'Adjetivo'), ('lemma', 'abandonado'), ('empresa', ''), ('entidad', ''), ('lugar', ''), ('tiempo', '')])